# *ngFor over multidimensional Array

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have a 2-dimensional variable

```
vals : number [] []
```

I try to use it in a table. How can I address a dimension to have the index of it?

```
<tr *ngFor="let idx2 = ???">
     <td *ngFor="let idx1 = ???">{{ values [idx1] [idx2] }}</td>
</tr>
```

**EDIT**: changed the sample to have the index switched

Comment: Why would you need the index? You want the values. Each value of the outer array is a row. Each value of the inner arrays is a cell. `<tr *ngFor="let row of vals"><td *ngFor="let cell of row">{{ cell }}</td></tr>`

Comment: Maybe the f1st for is not the 1st dimension

Comment: It is in your question. If you want to ask another question, then ask another question.

Comment: Yes, I changed the sample.sorry.

Comment: Then the best way is probably to transpose your array in the TypeScript code, and to display as I did above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for using indexes:

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of vals">
     <td *ngFor="let value of row">{{value}}</td>
</tr>
```

If you [need indexes](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#description):

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of vals; index as i">
     <td *ngFor="let value of row; index as k">{{value}}, {{vals[i][k]}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thats working if the 1st for is the 1st dimension and the 2nd for is the 2nd dimension... but if thats not the case I need the index, or?