# How to iterate objects inside array using ngFor?

Tags: html, typescript, angular5

I have an array with objects inside as below.

```
public feeds: any[] =[];

this.feeds["card_2"] = { cod: "66812720", des: "4X5kg", top: "Normal" };
this.feeds["card_6"] = { year: "YTD 2018", value: "17.1M" };
this.feeds["card_7"] = { year: "YTD 2019", value: "1.3M" };
this.feeds["card_8"] = { growthYTD: "-92.50%" };
```

I tried following code:

```
<div *ngFor ="let key of keys">
  {{key}}
  <tr *ngFor="let row of feeds[key]">
    <td>{{row.des}}</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</div>
```

But I am not being able to go inside loop and display anything.

Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\*ngFor over multidimensional Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53573583/ngfor-over-multidimensional-array)

Comment: I have tried it but it didnot worked with me.